# Know if the API is called by our app or a 3rd party app?

Tags: android, web-services

How to make sure that the API is called by our app itself and not a 3rd party app. If we use a application key people can reverse engineer our app and get the application key. so how to make sure that no one else is using the API?

Comment: "so how to make sure that no one else is using the API?" Easy. You don't. Everything you try is futile. Ask whatsapp

Comment: What sort of "API" are you referring to? Are you referring to some form of IPC offered by your Android app to other Android apps? Are you referring to some sort of API offered over the Internet, such as a Web service's API? Are you referring to something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare: I think user specifies to APIs / Webservices created by him for use in his application.

Comment: @CommonsWare Web service API

Comment: Then jr's answer is the most common solution.

Comment: @CommonsWare twitter allows its app to have unlimited users but other apps have a limit. if the API knows the client by the app key any app can use the same key and get token. right?

Comment: It's more that the on-the-wire protocol (i.e., the HTTP requests made of Twitter servers) is independent of the client. Somewhere, the API key is included in that protocol. It might be transformed (e.g., combined with the signing key hash of your app) in ways that preclude somebody from using the API key with Twitter's library. But anyone who can sniff on the HTTP protocol is likely to be able to get at information that allows them to make similar HTTP requests, effectively using somebody else's API key. I know of no way to prevent a determined attacker from doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Well nothing is 100% secure in this case but you can try your best to keep your key encrypted inside your app. Encrypt the key with some salt to request session token from the server (make their validity time dependent) and use xcsrf tokens.Do a latent login every time.

Use ProGuard to obfuscate your code.
Some people have suggested DexGuard(I have not used this though).Which delays the reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

If it is user information, add user authentication to your api flow. Other than that the best way I can think of is to have each user give you their email address and you send them a link there, so that they can be verified on your website. Then your API gives full access to the verified users only.